# Can't install phpmyadmin with yum RHEL 6

Tags: rhel6, phpmyadmin

I'm having difficulty getting phpmyadmin installed on a RHEL 6 server. I have tried to use on specific repo and have even tried installing the missing packages from another repo. I have still not been able to get this working.

Here is an output from the command line:

```
yum install phpmyadmin
Loaded plugins: product - id, rhnplugin, search - disabled - repos, security,: subscription - manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
-- > Running transaction check
-- - > Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0: 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6 will be installed
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - xmlwriter
for package: phpMyAdmin - 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - tcpdf - dejavu - sans - fonts
for package: phpMyAdmin - 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - tcpdf
for package: phpMyAdmin - 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - php - gettext
for package: phpMyAdmin - 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - mcrypt
for package: phpMyAdmin - 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - mbstring
for package: phpMyAdmin - 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - gd
for package: phpMyAdmin - 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Running transaction check
    -- - > Package php - gd.x86_64 0: 5.3 .3 - 49.e l6 will be installed
    -- > Processing Dependency: libXpm.so .4()(64 bit) for package: php - gd - 5.3 .3 - 49.e l6.x86_64
    -- - > Package php - mcrypt.x86_64 0: 5.3 .3 - 5.e l6 will be installed
    -- > Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so .4()(64 bit) for package: php - mcrypt - 5.3 .3 - 5.e l6.x86_64
    -- - > Package php - php - gettext.noarch 0: 1.0 .12 - 1.e l6 will be installed
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - mbstring
for package: php - php - gettext - 1.0 .12 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- - > Package php - tcpdf.noarch 0: 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6 will be installed
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - tidy
for package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - posix
for package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - mbstring
for package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - composer(fedora / autoloader) for package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - bcmath
for package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- - > Package php - tcpdf - dejavu - sans - fonts.noarch 0: 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6 will be installed
    -- - > Package php - xml.x86_64 0: 5.3 .3 - 49.e l6 will be installed
    -- - > Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0: 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6 will be installed
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - mbstring
for package: phpMyAdmin - 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Running transaction check
    -- - > Package libXpm.x86_64 0: 3.5 .10 - 2.e l6 will be installed
    -- - > Package libmcrypt.x86_64 0: 2.5 .8 - 9.e l6 will be installed
    -- - > Package php - fedora - autoloader.noarch 0: 0.2 .1 - 2.e l6 will be installed
    -- - > Package php - php - gettext.noarch 0: 1.0 .12 - 1.e l6 will be installed
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - mbstring
for package: php - php - gettext - 1.0 .12 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- - > Package php - tcpdf.noarch 0: 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6 will be installed
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - tidy
for package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - posix
for package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - mbstring
for package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - bcmath
for package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- - > Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0: 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6 will be installed
    -- > Processing Dependency: php - mbstring
for package: phpMyAdmin - 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6.noarch
    -- > Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch(epel)
Requires: php - posix
Error: Package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch(epel)
Requires: php - bcmath
Error: Package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch(epel)
Requires: php - tidy
Error: Package: phpMyAdmin - 4.0 .10 .19 - 1.e l6.noarch(epel)
Requires: php - mbstring
Error: Package: php - php - gettext - 1.0 .12 - 1.e l6.noarch(epel)
Requires: php - mbstring
Error: Package: php - tcpdf - 6.2 .13 - 1.e l6.noarch(epel)
Requires: php - mbstring
You could
try using--skip - broken to work around the problem
You could
try running: rpm - Va--nofiles--nodigest
```

Here is the repolist:

```
yum - v repolist
Loading "rhnplugin"
plugin
Loading "product-id"
plugin
Loading "search-disabled-repos"
plugin
Loading "security"
plugin
Loading "subscription-manager"
plugin
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Config time: 0.091
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Looking
for repo options
for [main]
Looking
for repo options
for [rhel - x86_64 - server - 6]
Repo 'rhel-x86_64-server-6'
setting option 'enabled' = '1'
Repo 'rhel-x86_64-server-6'
setting option 'gpgcheck' = '1'
Yum Version: 3.2 .29
Setting up Package Sacks
pkgsack time: 0.042
Repo - id: epel
Repo - name: Extra Packages
for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64
Repo - revision: 1491872280
Repo - tags: binary - x86_64
Repo - updated: Mon Apr 10 21: 27: 56 2017
Repo - pkgs: 12, 300
Repo - size: 11 G
Repo - metalink: https: //mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64
    Updated: Mon Apr 10 21: 27: 56 2017
Repo - baseurl: http: //mirror.compevo.com/epel/6/x86_64/ (26 more)
    Repo - expire: 21, 600 second(s)(last: Tue Apr 11 10: 19: 30 2017)
Repo - id: remi - safe
Repo - name: Safe Remi 's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64
Repo - revision: 1491832217
Repo - updated: Mon Apr 10 09: 50: 21 2017
Repo - pkgs: 1, 769
Repo - size: 333 M
Repo - mirrors: http: //rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/safe/mirror
    Repo - baseurl: http: //rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/safe/x86_64/ (32 more)
    Repo - expire: 21, 600 second(s)(last: Tue Apr 11 10: 19: 31 2017)
Repo - id: rhel - x86_64 - server - 6
Repo - name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server(v.6
    for 64 - bit x86_64)
Repo - updated: Tue Apr 11 06: 51: 05 2017
Repo - pkgs: 19, 465
Repo - size: 36 G
Repo - baseurl: https: //xmlrpc.rhn.redhat.com/XMLRPC/GET-REQ/rhel-x86_64-server-6
    Repo - expire: 21, 600 second(s)(last: Tue Apr 11 10: 19: 32 2017)
repolist: 33, 534
```

**Server version uname -r 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64**

Last here is the information on php

```
yum info php
Loaded plugins: product - id, rhnplugin, search - disabled - repos, security,: subscription - manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Installed Packages
Name: php
Arch: x86_64
Version: 5.3 .3
Release: 49.e l6
Size: 3.5 M
Repo: installed
From repo: rhel - x86_64 - server - 6
Summary: PHP scripting language
for creating dynamic web sites
URL: http: //www.php.net/
    License: PHP
Description: PHP is an HTML - embedded scripting language.PHP attempts to make: it easy
for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.: PHP also offers built - in database integration
for several
    : commercial and non - commercial database management systems, so: writing a database - enabled webpage with PHP is fairly simple.The: most common use of PHP coding is probably as a replacement
for: CGI scripts.:
    : The php package contains the module which adds support
for the
    : PHP language to Apache HTTP Server.
```

I have also tried running a yum update and also cleaning to make sure everything is up to date. I appreciate the help!

Comment: At least, the "optional" channel is missing.

Comment: @RemiCollet I'm not sure what you mean by "optional" could you go into more detail please? Thanks

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Subscription_Management/1/html/RHSM/supplementary-repos.html